# Parse words in PHP

Tags: php, string

From the string of words, can I get only the words with a capitalized first letter?  For example, I have this string:

> Page and Brin originally nicknamed THEIR new search engine "BackRub",
>   because the system checked backlinks to estimate the importance of a
>   site.

I need to get: Page, Brin, THEIR, BackRub

Comment: You can use the standard php code for this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: str_word_count() with a type argument of `1`, then array_filter() for words with an uppercase character as the first character... `$result = array_filter(str_word_count($myString,1), function($value) { return $value[0] == strtoupper($value[0]); }`

Comment: @MarkBaker but using strpos that's case sensitive?

Answer (score 4):

A non-regex solution (based on Mark Baker's comment):

```
$result = array_filter(str_word_count($str, 1), function($item) {
    return ctype_upper($item[0]);
});

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Page
    [2] => Brin
    [5] => THEIR
    [9] => BackRub
)
```

Comment: Cleaner than mine using `ctype_upper`, though I still like doing it as a 1-liner passing the result of `str_word_count()` directly to array_filter rather than needing the memory overhead of another variable

Comment: @MarkBaker: Yeah, you're right. Changed it into a one-liner :)

Comment: Like that solution, because I learned something new :) Well done Amal

Comment: Still has twice the runtime cost of a regular expression.  Check it yourselves  https://gist.github.com/Saeven/8318339

Comment: @AmalMurali Sure that's definitely a quote they'll push on you in a first year course, and I do agree with it when we concern ourselves with conceptual matter.  Using loops and explosions and any variety of artifice native or custom to search a string when we've got regex in our back pocket? Regex is hardly premature optimization.

Comment: If speed is a concern, then you could use foreach instead of array_filter(): http://gist.github.com/amalmurali47/8318735 –

Comment: @Saeven: Deleted the other comment. That's not what I actually meant. We don't really know what the OP's purpose is -- so 'speed' doesn't really matter. If he wanted an optimized solution, he should have stated that in the question itself :)

Answer (score 3):

You can match that with

```
preg_match("/[A-Z]{1}[a-zA-z]*/um", $searchText)
```

You can see on `php.net` how `preg_match` can be applied.
https://www.php.net/preg_match

**EDIT, TO ADD EXAMPLE**

Here's an example of how to get the array with full matches

```
$searchText = 'Page and Brin originally nicknamed THEIR new search engine "BackRub", because the system checked backlinks to estimate the importance of a site.';
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]{1}[a-zA-z]*/um", $searchText, $matches );
var_dump( $matches );
```

The output is:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
  array(4) {
        [0]=>
    string(4) "Page"
        [1]=>
    string(4) "Brin"
        [2]=>
    string(5) "THEIR"
        [3]=>
    string(7) "BackRub"
  }
}
```

Comment: That'll include `THEIRS`, too.

Comment: I like the idea of using a regex for this, but this fails for e.g. "THEIRS".

Comment: You're not saving the matches.  You need to use the 3rd argument of `preg_match`.

Comment: @PatrickQ that's why I posted the link to php.net, I'm sure they can figure out what they need.

Comment: I can only get this to match the first word in a string. Have you testet it @Saeven?

Comment: Should be `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`

Comment: What if we're using words by teenagers, or like music? This would not match "Hi5, R2D2", or "I love U2".

Comment: He asked for words in the real sense of a word I think, but if you wanted to be very lenient and catch any string, you could change the second class to be "not whitespace" rather than "any letter"

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is explode by space, ucfirst the exploded strings, and check them against the original.

here is what I mean:

```
$str = 'Page and Brin originally nicknamed THEIR new search engine "BackRub", because the system checked backlinks to estimate the importance of a site.';

$strings = explode(' ', $str);

$i = 0;
$out = array();
foreach($strings as $s)
{
    if($strings[$i] == ucfirst($s))
    {
        $out[] = $s;
    }
    ++$i;
}

var_dump($out);
```

http://codepad.org/QwrS4HpE

Answer (score 0):

I would use strtok function (https://www.php.net/strtok), which returns the words in the string, one by one. You can specify the delimiter between words:

```
$string = 'Page and Brin originally nicknamed THEIR new search engine "BackRub", because the system checked backlinks to estimate the importance of a site.';
$delimiter = ' ,."'; // specify valid delimiters here (add others as needed)
$capitalized_words = array(); // array to hold the found words

$tok = strtok($string,$delimiter); // get first token
while ($tok !== false) {
    $first_char = substr($tok,0,1);
    if (strtoupper($first_char)===$first_char) {
        // this word ($tok) is capitalized, store it
        $capitalized_words[] = $tok;
    }
    $tok = strtok($delimiter); // get next token
}

var_dump($capitalized_words); // print the capitalized words found
```

This prints:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Page"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Brin"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "THEIR"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "BackRub"
}
```

Good luck!

Only drawback I can see is that it doesn't handle multibyte. If you have only English characters, then you're ok. If you have international characters, a modified/different solution may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using explode and loop through with regex:

```
$string = 'Page and Brin originally nicknamed THEIR new search engine "BackRub", because the system checked backlinks to estimate the importance of a site.';
$list = explode(' ',$string);
$matches = array();

foreach($list as $str) {
    if(preg_match('/[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*/um',$str) $matches[] = $str;
}

print_r($matches);
```